# How to set my android webview to remember new passwords?

Tags: android, passwords, webview, android-alertdialog, remember-me

I'm loading a webpage (for example mail.yahoo.com) in a webview. After entering username and password an AlertDialog shows asking me if I wanna remember the password which I do.

The thing is that after logging out, if another user wants to login, after he enters his own username and password, the AlertDialog asking whether to remember the password does NOT show anymore and so the old username and password are remembered.

What I want is a way to set the webview to remember the latest username and passwords that were entered. Cause (for example) if the users enters wrong username or password for the first time (after app is installed) and checks them to be remembered he wont't be able to modify the wrong entered ones and save the correct ones instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, the only way to do it.  If you change a password you will need to reset everything with the stock app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear user and password first in WebView Database with this code:

```
WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearUsernamePassword();
```